# How to replace a part of a string with a variable PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

I am pretty novice in PHP, and so this may seem like it's an obvious answer but I can't figure it out.

I have this string here

```
$get_xenuser_data_url = "http://phanime.com/community/api.php?action=getUser&value=USER_ID&hash=asdfasdf";
```

And I need to replace where it says `USER_ID` with this variable `$xenuser_id` So how would I go about it?

Essentially I want something like this

```
"http://phanime.com/community/api.php?action=getUser&value=$xenuser_id&hash=asdfasdf"
```

Comment: This is a **very** basic question. Sufficient information is provided in the always-useful [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) I suggest you start there.

Comment: Did you happen to *try* your second line of code? As far as I can tell, it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
str_replace('USER_ID', $xenuser_id, $get_xenuser_data_url);
```

Comment: Easy and reliable! Best way to do it! Just don't forget the semicolon!

Comment: sorry, I was very excited to be the first one to post :D